# Make radio button have a default of what it starts on

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a 'PartActionType' declared in my model that looks like this

```
    public enum PartActionType
    {
        Transfer,
        Harvest,
        Dispose
    }
```

In my view page I use this to display the 3 options

```
 @foreach (var actionType in partActionTypes)
    {
      <td>
         @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Components[i].SelectedActionType, actionType)
      </td>
    }
```

How can I make it default to one option for my example I want the 'Transfer' RadioBox to be the default option.

Here's whats happening after taking Davids suggestion

[image: View]

Comment: I don't code razor but I think you can find control after for loop and set select = true
or write javascript code it's better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You default the selected action type when you initialize your view model. Don't ever put many if-else statements in your view.

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var vm = new ItemViewModel
    {
        ItemId = 123,
        ItemName = "Fake Item",
        Components = new List<ItemComponentViewModel>
        {
            new ItemComponentViewModel
            {
                ComponentId = 1,
                ComponentName = "Part 1",
                SelectedActionType = PartActionType.Transfer
            },
            new ItemComponentViewModel
            {
                ComponentId = 2,
                ComponentName = "Part 2",
                SelectedActionType = PartActionType.Transfer
            },
            ...        
        };
    };

    return View(vm);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But for some reason it is skipping some parts and not checking anything

Comment: If you're fetching the data from your persistence storage, you might need logic to convert whatever the part action type to the enum. I just came up the idea of putting the action types as enum. You might not save them as enum in your database.

Comment: Actually yeah the issue came back I'll add a screenshot of what it looks like in my question

Comment: I added it in. As you can see most of the values are checked, but for some reason some aren't

Comment: Again, I don't know how they're stored in your database. You might have to convert them to the enum. If they don't exist in the enum, you will have to add them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
foreach (var actionType in partActionTypes)
    {
      if (actionType == PartActionType.Transfer)
      <td>
         @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Components[i].SelectedActionType, actionType, new {@checked="checked"})
      </td>
else
      <td>
         @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Components[i].SelectedActionType, actionType)
      </td>
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! However I'm receiving an error of **Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'partActionType'**